# Get data attribute value in Symfony controller

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, symfony3.x

In my **View**, I have this hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="logoID" name="logoID" class="logoID" value="123">
```

I **add additional data** to it using **data attribute** via jQuery like this

```
$('.logoID').data('fileName', 'xyz.jpg')  
// adds data attribute to input element -> <input ... data-fileName='xyz.jpg' />
```

Now I need to retrieve this `fileName` **inside** my **controller**. I know I can get **value** of this hidden field by

```
$form['logoID']->getData();       // 123
```

But I also need the **value of the data-attribute** (`fileName`). How can I go about it? Any leads are much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just add it as another hidden field?

Comment: Try setting a JSON value to the `logoID` hidden field and in your controller use `json_decode()`.

Comment: @JasonRoman yes, I know I could send it as another hidden field, but I wanted to know if there was another way to do it..

Comment: @yceruto yeah, seems like a small hack. Although my form validation would get screwed up then. So, can't really implement it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-attributes` are not available directly by the PHP scripts. You need to send that value using another hidden input or retrieve the value with Jquery later and post it as data using Ajax.

Comment: hmmm. I'm still researching a little more incase I come across something. thanks though.

Comment: What do you have against using another hidden field?  I'm not understanding.

Comment: @JasonRoman lol. Nothing really, I'm only searching if there exists another way to do it.